# Regular Expression query for MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
I have users collection with these documents.
[
    {
        email:'abc+100@gmail.com'
    },{
        email:'abc+2345@gmail.com',
    },{
        email:'abc+234577@gmail.com',
    },{
        email:'abc+23450077@gmail.com',
    },{
        email:'abc+23450077-345@gmail.com',
    }
]
I want to search users with partial email or full email like ex--
req.body.email='abc+2345';//partial search
let email = req.body.email;
req.body.email='abc+234577@gmail.com';//full email search
```

Mongo query to search partial or full using Regx

```
Users.find({$or:[{ 'email': { $regex: email, '$options': 'i' }}]})
```

It is unable to find users whose email contain `'abc+2345'` or `'abc+234577@gmail.com'`.

Answer (score 0):

We need to escape '+' in the regex. The following query can also get you the expected output:

```
db.check.find({"email":/abc\+2345/i}).pretty()
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4a4735cbfa696dcd99249f"),
    "email" : "abc+2345@gmail.com"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4a4735cbfa696dcd9924a0"),
    "email" : "abc+234577@gmail.com"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4a4735cbfa696dcd9924a1"),
    "email" : "abc+23450077@gmail.com"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4a4735cbfa696dcd9924a2"),
    "email" : "abc+23450077-345@gmail.com"
}
```

Comment: How i'll use escape character in regx using variable name like email??

Comment: @sameer Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

do  it like this

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.user.find({$or :[{ email: { $regex: /^abc\+2345/ ,$options :'i'} },{email:"six666@gmail.com"}]})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4a477dd72dc9d0a4b71d85"), "email" : "abc+2345@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4a477dd72dc9d0a4b71d86"), "email" : "abc+234577@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4a477dd72dc9d0a4b71d87"), "email" : "abc+23450077@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4a477dd72dc9d0a4b71d88"), "email" : "abc+23450077-345@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4a4b67d72dc9d0a4b71d89"), "email" : "six666@gmail.com" }
MongoDB Enterprise >
```

in `$or`  the  first  stage  is with regex  ,second  used  for full match

Comment: in $or the first stage is with regex,you have used with static email value; but i want escaping with dynamic email value using just req.body.email

Comment: with  mongo shell  or  driver  api ?

Comment: with driver api using node mongoose

Comment: you have to use  `pattern`  with it  now .   only  when  your data  is very  simple . you can try  `string pattern`